Axios response json string is broken in React Native
I'm using axios in React Native project and weird thing happens frequently.
In React Native project, it fetches data from server side (Laravel in this case)
And the json response is become invalid on React Native frequently.
I tested the api on Postman and the response is normal
So I logged on the app, and found that json string is invalid when the response is long.

As you can see, nul is placed instead of null
Sometimes, " is missing, like this

It happens indeterministic way.
Not sure where the problem is: Server side or RN or Axios?

How are you returning your json from laravel? How are you handling the json received from laravel to your react native after ajax request? Post your relevant code so that we can help you identify the issue.

btw, Don't post your json as an image but post them as code.

Thank you for your reply. Have you ever encountered such a thing before. FYI, I return response from laravel with response()->json($data). And above json was got from axios response, and no further process.
